# What are the differences between one's complement and ones' complement? Or are there no differences?

Tags: c

There is a sentence on page 48 of the C Programming Language (K&R), "The unary operator ~ yields the **one's complement** of an integer; that is, it converts each 1-bit into a 0-bit and vice versa", here one's complement should mean bitwise negation operation, right?

In my opinion,ones' complement is ones' complement, not one's complement. Actually it is specifically stated in the book CSAPP that Ones' complement.Am I being too picky or are the two really different?

I mainly read the two books K&R and CSAPP. In addition, Google can't find the answer to my question. I want to be very clear about the answer to this question.

Comment: Proofreaders and editors can't catch all the mistakes in book, it's just a way of life that your text-books will have errors. Spelling and punctuation are the most common, but I've seen much worse.

Comment: There's nothing called "ones' complement". Your question isn't even about programming but about proper English spelling...

Comment: @Lundin I stand corrected and removed my wikipedia link (but perhaps that was premature, looking at the answers below)

Comment: @Lundin But Wikipedia calls it [`ones' complement`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement)?

Comment: We can have complement by one or two. Which is used? One's complement. We do not have complement by ones and twos and therefore we do not have ones' complement. Unless you know some guy named Ones.

Comment: Knuth writes: ''Detail-oriented readers and copy editors should notice the position of the apostrophe in terms like "two's complement" and "ones' complement": A two's complement number is complemented with respect to a single power of 2, while a ones' complement number is complemented with respect to a long sequence of 1s.'' — Knuth, Donald E. "4.1. Positional Number Systems". The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms (3rd ed.).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The same article also mention "two's complement". Why ones' and then two's? Wikipedia is inconsistent.

Comment: @Lundin "Complement to all 1s" (aka xor to all ones), but "complement to two". I'm more confused about the latter.

Comment: @IanAbbott Still doesn't make sense. Why would 1's complement be plural and 2's complement singular?

Comment: There are many ones, they have a complement. Therefore it is ones' complement.

Comment: @Lundin Two's complement refers to the single power of two that changes the sign. The reason max_x + 1 = min_x

Comment: @Lundin Because we're talking about a single 2 (power of two) vs multiple 1s (all bits set).

Comment: @matt If we have `1` (one one, singularis) and then take its bitwise complement `~1` we get `0xFF...FE`. Which in one's complement is -1.

Comment: @Lundin Right, if you had a bit, then you could say the one's complement but your int has multiple bits and you're taking the one complement of each bit. It is true your example only starts with one 1 bit but ends with n 1 bits.

Comment: @matt Many bits but just one 1...

Comment: @Lundin, from Wikipedia: «The name "ones' complement" (sic)[1] refers to the fact that such an inverted value, if added to the original, would always produce an "all ones" number». (The footnote, [1] is the Knuth citation I mentioned earlier.)

Comment: @IanAbbott So a two's complement number would then result in an "all twos" number... This isn't making any sense.

Comment: ...also, is it _signed magnitude_ or _sign and magnitude_...

Comment: @Lundin There is a difference between two's complement and twos' complement. A twos' complement would involve the subtraction of each digit of a base-3 number from 2, producing an "all twos" number when added to the original.  Cf. the nines' complement of a decimal number involves the subtraction of each digit from 9, producing an "all nines" number when added to the original. (Nines' complement is a common technique used by mechanical calculators.) If you add 1 to the nines' complement of a number, you get the ten's complement. (Note the position of the apostrophe).

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes I can buy the reasoning as explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements. But again - says Knuth. Who was it that actually invented these terms?

Comment: If the apostrophes are too confusing, two's complement is the base 2 *radix complement* and ones' complement is the base 2 *diminished radix complement*.

Comment: @Lundin I suspect the terms "ten's complement" and "nines' complement" would have been used first, and the terms "two's complement" and "ones' complement" would have been adapted from those.

Comment: @Lundin The wikipedia "Method of complements" article also has the same typo in its link to "One's complement". I think I will fix it.

Comment: Also wouldn't there be a base 1 diminished radix complement and what's that called then...

Comment: @Lundin Base 1 is not a radix counting system, so it doesn't apply.

Comment: @IanAbbott Mathematically it ought to exist yeah? The value 0 in base 1 can be expressed as digit*base^n, more specifically 0*1^0 = 0.

Comment: Thank you for your discussion and responses, they are very helpful to me. This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, and I may not have done a good job in many aspects, such as the format of the question and the way to ask the question... However, I hope that my question is valuable and not a waste of anyone's time. In conclusion, thank you all.

Comment: @Lundin On examination of the "Method of complements" Wikipedia article the convention of apostrophe placement does indeed seem to be due to Knuth as you suspected.

Comment: @Gipsyfine I think we all learned something. I did.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, you *could* represent 0 in (radix) base 1, but you couldn't represent any other value!

Comment: @Gipsyfine I think you hit a bit of a sweet spot, something that is off topic but pedantic. In the future you should try to include some code and be clear with your question about programming.

Answer (score 4):

> What are the differences between one's complement and ones' complement? Or are there no differences?

"One's complement" is a common misspelling (mis-punctuation) of "ones' complement".  The latter is conventional.  The persistence of the former may be related to the fact that "two's complement" is the correct spelling / punctuation of a more popular alternative for representing signed integers.

Wikipedia notes this detail in [its article on the format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), citing and quoting Donald Knuth in *The Art of Computer Programming*:

> Detail-oriented readers and copy editors should notice the position of the apostrophe in terms like "two's complement" and "ones' complement": A two's complement number is complemented with respect to a single power of 2, while a ones' complement number is complemented with respect to a long sequence of 1s.

Inasmuch as the question is tagged [C], it is also worth noting that every version of the C language spec that so far has been published uses "ones' complement" (for example, C17 6.2.6.2/2).  The next version of the spec no longer refers to that representation, however, specifying two's complement as the only conforming representation for signed integers.

> one's complement should mean bitwise negation operation, right?

"One's complement" is not a separate thing.  It's just misspelled.  But yes, with ones' complement representation, bitwise complement is equivalent to arithmetic negation.

Comment: This doesn't really prove anything, it's anecdotal evidence. Donald Knuth may be a well-regarded computer scientist, but we need a better argument than "Knuth says so". Specifically: why was the term named in a certain way from the beginning and by whom. I'm not sure if "programming etymology" is even on-topic here.

Comment: @Lundin, Knuth says so, *and* explains why, in one of the seminal works teaching Computer Science.  And, inasmuch as the question is tagged C, "ones' complement" is the punctuation used by every version of the language spec that mentions the representation at all.

Comment: I found a slightly better explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements where they speak of "radix complement" vs "diminished radix complement". This is at least an argument and I could almost buy the explanation, if I could find a better first source for it.

Comment: And we posted that link almost the same second, heh... maybe we complement each other... :)

Comment: Anyway this seems to be a notation invented by Knuth. So of course he would recommend it. I don't believe he invented the term one's/ones' complement however.

Answer (score 3):

The unary operator-`~` does indeed perform a ones' complement operation, a bitwise negation.

---

It's easy to verify that the book is referring to ones' complement. The definition of "one's complement" you quoted from the book:

> it converts each 1-bit into a 0-bit and vice versa

The definition of [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement):

> The ones' complement of a binary number is the value obtained by inverting (flipping) all the bits in the binary representation of the number.

They're the same.

I don't know why the book used "one's complement". Maybe that was the preferred name at the time. Maybe there was a lack of consensus on the name at the time. Or maybe it's an error. It's an easy one to make considering the oddness of "ones'" as a word, and considering the existence of the confusingly similar two's complement.<sup>[1]</sup> Whatever the reason, "one's complement" should always be understood to be a reference to ones' complement.

---

1. The two similar operations/systems derive their names as follows:

   - "Ones' complement" is short for "complement of a sequence of ones" (111...1<sub>2</sub> - x)
   - "Two's complement" is short for "complement of a power of two".  (2<sup>n</sup> - x)